# Circular Dependency in Component for Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have three  angular material Dialog, on click of back button it should open the previous dialog but when I am trying to do so I am getting Circular Dependency Issue

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\shared\dialog\continue-popup\continue-popup.component.ts -> src\app\shared\dialog\show-cart\show-cart.component.ts -> src\app\shared\dialog\checkout-popup\checkout-popup.component.ts ->
src\app\shared\dialog\continue-popup\continue-popup.component.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\shared\dialog\show-cart\show-cart.component.ts -> src\app\shared\dialog\checkout-popup\checkout-popup.component.ts -> src\app\shared\dialog\continue-popup\continue-popup.component.ts ->
src\app\shared\dialog\show-cart\show-cart.component.ts
```

This code in last popup is causing the issue

```
gotoPaymentInfo() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.dialogService.openDialog(CheckoutPopupComponent, this.countryList);
}
```

I am not sure how to fix it if I try to use subject it is causing abrupt behavior while closing the popup.Can you please suggest what is the correct way to resolve the error.
In checkout component on click of ok I am calling this.dialogServie.openDialog(ContinuePopupComponent) whereas on back button click of  ContinuePopupComponent I am calling  this.dialogServie.openDialog(CheckoutPopupComponent) which is causing the issue

Comment: If there is circular dependency check your constructors, it happens when X injects Y and Y injects X, take a quick look on your constructors and you should figure out why this problem happens, maybe I am wrong, can you show your code here?

Answer (score 0):

If this a service you're adding the component for, you could add the component as a method param and add via in component the service method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the issue, it was because I was trying to open Dialog a from Dialog b and again on click of back button from Dialog b to a.
I resolved the issue by using Behavior Subject on click of back button.